# Linker errors when using openNI on OS X 10.8

Tags: openni

I have been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now.  I have searched on the OpenNI forums as well as here, and I have tried fixes that worked for others but I am still getting linker errors.
I'll start from the beginning:  I installed OpenNI 2.0 for OSX using the command line ./install.  everything went good.  It created the environment variables:

```
export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/Users/Robert/Documents/Kinect/OpenNI-2.0.0/Include
export OPENNI2_REDIST=/Users/Robert/Documents/Kinect/OpenNI-2.0.0/Redist
```

I went into xCode and follows the instructions Here http://cicconet.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/openni-and-xcode-4/
to get xcode working with OpenNI SDK
I added /usr/include/ni to the “Header Search Paths” and added libOpenNI.dylib to the framework folder as well as putting it in the project's directory.
Xcode intellasence has all of the OpenNI methods and I do not get any errors when writing the code.
The code I use is:

```
#include <OpenNI.h>
using namespace openni;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    OpenNI::initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

the errors I am getting are:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_oniInitialize", referenced from:
      openni::OpenNI::initialize() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I forgetting to include something somewhere?

Comment: Haven't tried OpenNI 2.0 yet, but it looks like you're not linking against a 64bit (x86_64) OpenNI dylib. Have you compiled the OpenNI library yourself ? Can you compile/get a 64bit version of it ? Otherwise, you might need to set your XCode project's architecture to 32bit. HTH